# Ruby on rails Stripe - set default amount to shopping cart subtotal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to connect my shopping cart to Stripe and set the amount to the order subtotal of my cart. I tried defining order_subtotal in my orders model and tried to pass it though the amount field in my stripe code but I get the following error when I go through check out: Invalid integer: order_subtotal

I cant find any online that explains how to connect an amount that varies to stripe using the ruby language. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
       @amount = :order_subtotal


      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      =>  :order_subtotal,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end end
```

cart/show.html.erb

```
<div class="shopping-cart">   <%= render "shopping_cart" %> <%= form_tag charges_path do %>   <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>:order_subtotal</span>
    </label>   </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key=ENV[PUBLISHABLE_KEY]
          data-description="Checkout"
          data-amount= "amount"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-shipping-address="null"
          >   </script>
           <% end %> </div>
```

_shopping_cart.html.erb

```
<% if !@order_item.nil? && @order_item.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
    <% @order_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% if @order_items.size == 0 %>
  <p class="text-center">
    There are no items in your shopping cart.  Please <%= link_to "go back", root_path %> and add some items to your cart.
  </p>
<% else %>
  <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
    <%= render 'carts/cart_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item, show_total: true %>
  <% end %>
   <p class="text-center">Order SubTotal=<%= order_subtotal= @order_items.sum(:total_price)%></p>

<% end %>
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base   
belongs_to :order_status   
has_many :order_items   
before_create :set_order_status  
before_save :update_subtotal   


 def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0}.sum   
end   
def order_subtotal  
 @order_items.sum(:total_price)   end end private   def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1   end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal   end
```

Comment: Replace `:amount => :order_subtotal` with `:amount => order_subtotal`. You are adding a symbol instead of the result of the `order_subtotal` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `charges_controller.rb` replace

```
:amount => :order_subtotal
```

with

```
:amount => order_subtotal
```

You are adding a symbol instead of the result of the `order_subtotal` method.

Also in your **cart/show.html.erb** you probably want

```
<span><%= order_subtotal %></span>
```

instead of

```
<span>:order_subtotal</span>
```

About this line:

```
<p class="text-center">Order SubTotal=<%= order_subtotal= @order_items.sum(:total_price)%></p>
```

Since you seem not to have an order instance when your cart is being charged for, you cannot access `Order#order_subtotal` method. It's therefore best to have a helper method like `cart_subtotal` to calculate displayed values instead of doing that right in the template.